# How to get the hash of a smart contract deployment transaction with only a smart contract address?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is it possible to derive the hash of a smart contract deployment transaction using only a smart contract address? If so, what is the best way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless you need to automate it, the simplest way is probably just to use Etherscan.

Just go to [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/) and paste the contract address in the search bar.

Then in the "more info" section of the page about the contract you will see

`ContractCreator: 0xabcd... at txn 0xabcd...`

Click on the txn, and it will give you all the information about that transaction, including the hash.

Comment: But how does etherscan get it? What if we need to automate it, and want a decentralized technique rather than relying on etherscan or some other centralized service?